# Нужна помощь в задаче Python

Tags: python

По заданию нужно написать программу-калькулятор, которая:
в первой строке считывает число (начальный результат);
в последующих строках считывает символ мат. операции и число, применяет операцию к результату;
как только прочитан символ «=», выводит результат и завершает работу.
Программа должна обрабатывать некорректный ввод. Обычный калькулятор написать могу, а вот с этим - гигантские проблемы, подскажите, пожалуйста. Вот код.

Пример:

1. 1
2. +2
3. *3
4. **2
5. =81

```
A = float(input("Введите первое число "))
D = float()
G = float()
attempts = 0
while True:
    B = input("Введите знак и второе число ")
    if B == '=':
        print(D)
        break
    else:  
       E = str(B[0])
       C = float(B[1])
    if attempts <= 0:
        D += D - A

    if E == '+':
        D += A+C
        attempts += 1
    elif E == '-':
        D += A - C
        attempts += 1
    elif E == '*':
        D += A * C
        attempts += 1
    elif E == '/':
        D += A / C
        attempts += 1
    else:
        print("Некорректный ввод")
```

Comment: И что ваш код не работает?

Comment: Да, выдаёт какую-то лютую жесть)

Comment: Если при плюс/минус - он работает кое-как, то на делении/умножении выдаёт полный абсурд.

Comment: А почему вы всё время проводите операции с `А` если у вас результат после предыдущей операции хранится в `D`?

Comment: А - это же первое число, поэтому и проводятся операции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот оптимизированный код:

```
firstNumber = float(input("Введите первое число "))

result = float(firstNumber)

while True:
    operation_and_number = input("Введите знак и второе число ")

    if (operation_and_number[0] == "="):
        print(f"Result: {result}")
        break

    if (operation_and_number[0] == "+"):
        result += float(operation_and_number[1:])

    elif (operation_and_number[0] == "-"):
        result -= float(operation_and_number[1:])

    elif (operation_and_number[0] == "*"):
        result *= float(operation_and_number[1:])

    elif (operation_and_number[0] == "/"):
        result /= float(operation_and_number[1:])
    else:
        print("Выбрана неверная операция!")
```

Comment: Гм... Первое число загнать сразу в `result` - и не надо никаких `iterations` и спец. обработки для первой операции.

Comment: Да, так было бы лучше. Говорю же, код не оптимизировал

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то в Питоне не особо сильно разбираюсь)